# Error - invalid token '(' in class struct or interface member declaration in c#

Tags: c#, invalid-characters

My code is -

```
public partial class App : Application
{

    HarvestApp.GoogleAPIManager GAPImanager = new HarvestApp.GoogleAPIManager();

    List<Event>todayCalendar = GAPImanager.GetCalendarEventsForDate(DateTime.Today);

    HarvestApp.HarvestManager HAPIManager = new HarvestApp.HarvestManager();

    Console.WriteLine("Entries found for Today :" + todayCalendar.Count);

    foreach(Event todayEvent in todayCalendar)
    {
        var addEvent = new HarvestApp.Harvest_TimeSheetEntry(todayEvent);
        EntryList.Add(addEvent);
        HAPIManager.postHarvestEntry(addEvent);
    }

 }
```

It gives me token error. Please help.

Comment: On what line do you get the error?

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that you did put your code directly in the class and not inside a member like a constructor:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        HarvestApp.GoogleAPIManager GAPImanager = new HarvestApp.GoogleAPIManager();

        List<Event>todayCalendar = GAPImanager.GetCalendarEventsForDate(DateTime.Today);

        HarvestApp.HarvestManager HAPIManager = new HarvestApp.HarvestManager();

        Console.WriteLine("Entries found for Today :" + todayCalendar.Count);

        foreach(Event todayEvent in todayCalendar)
        {
            var addEvent = new HarvestApp.Harvest_TimeSheetEntry(todayEvent);
            EntryList.Add(addEvent);
            HAPIManager.postHarvestEntry(addEvent);
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't declare code instructions like:

```
Console.WriteLine("Entries found for Today :" + todayCalendar.Count);

foreach(Event todayEvent in todayCalendar)
{
    var addEvent = new HarvestApp.Harvest_TimeSheetEntry(todayEvent);
    EntryList.Add(addEvent);
    HAPIManager.postHarvestEntry(addEvent);
}
```

in your class body.

You should make these calls in a constructor, or a specific method.